# How to reference foreign table column when doing group by

Tags: postgresql

TableA

id | b_id

TableB

id | name

```
select b_id, count(*) from TableA group by b_id order by count(*) asc
```

I am getting the result as

```
50 1
100 2
150 3
```

I want corresponding names to 50,100, 150 as my result

```
item50 1
item100 2
item150 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add the `name` column to the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` clauses:

```
SELECT
    b.id,
    b.name,
    COUNT(a.b_id) AS cnt
FROM TableB b
LEFT JOIN TableA a
    ON b.id = a.b_id
GROUP BY
    b.id,
    b.name
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select tableB.name||tableA.b_id:: character varying as b_id,count(*)
from tableA 
inner join tableB on tableA.b_id = tableB.id
group by tableB.name,tableA.b_id
```